# Values added for New Fields in registration form are not getting saved in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

In spree Provided default registration form i was trying to add my few fields :contact_no, :address, :full_name.

Copied the complete view part from "spree_auth_devise" as Spree internally uses this Gem.

Added required form fields in `app/views/spree/shared/_user_form.html.erb`

Added required Migration

```
class AddUserRegistrationDetailsToSpreeUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :spree_users, :full_name, :string
    add_column :spree_users, :address, :text
    add_column :spree_users, :contact_no, :integer
  end
end
```

Now following Model part : 
user_registration_decorator.rb

```
Spree::User.class_eval do 
       attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                       :contact_no, :address,:full_name, :as => [:default, :user]
end
```

Now on creating a new user via registration form, in Database the newly added fields(contact_no, address, full_name) are saved with NULL Value. :(

Comment: Which version of Spree are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spree 2.1.3 runs on Rails 4, and has followed Rails 4 to make the switch to [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).  You can read more about it in this blog post on the [Rails Blog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/), but basically attr_accessible is no longer used, and has been replaced with explicitly allowed parameters in the controller.

You should take a look at modifying [these attributes](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/b73ea0272d08dd22f5fcc27e905e84bd6297bef1/core/lib/spree/permitted_attributes.rb#L90-L91) which are used by the [user registrations controller](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/862921a8c32319d2a64c85bf2305a7d62cc3aa2a/app/controllers/spree/user_registrations_controller.rb#L68-L70).

Comment: That did my job after passing attributes to strong parameter list.